# Screen flickering with CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

```
    public Notice() {
        InitializeComponent();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
    }
    private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.StartsWith("CefSharp"))
        {
            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2)[0] + ".dll";
            string architectureSpecificPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                assemblyName);

            return File.Exists(architectureSpecificPath)
                ? Assembly.LoadFile(architectureSpecificPath)
                : null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void InitChrome()
    {
        Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();

        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
                                    Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
                                    "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe")
        };
        
        if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
            Cef.Initialize(settings);

        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(page);
        chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
        //chromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += ChromeBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

There is a parent form and an mdi child form.
I used ChromiumWebBrowser in child form.
ChromiumWebBrowser keeps blinking when mouse pointer is on parent form.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What version are you using? Exact version number please.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce when you use a form as a MDI child?  You can test with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: v91.1.230 
This is the latest version.

Comment: I made a sample and tested it.

There is no problem in the sample code, so you should check the internal source.

Comment: What example are you referring to? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example